# typescript: how to return proper type from generic function constrained by lookup type generic returning union

Tags: typescript, generics

So let's say we have following function implementation:

```
type Action = 'GREET' |'ASK'

function getUnion<T extends Action>(action: T) {
  switch (action) {
  case 'GREET':
    return {hello: 'Guten Tag!'} as const
  case 'ASK':
    return {time: 'Wie spat is es?'} as const
  default:
    return 'WUT?'
  }
}
```

Return type of this function is following union:

`{"WUT?" | { hello: 'Guten Tag!'; time?: undefined; } | { time: 'Wie spat is es?'; hello?: undefined; }}`

So what we may think is that if we use the function constraint by our generic by "discriminant union" type used inside the switch-case, it would return that particular branch type, like following:

```
//  NOPE !
// $ExpectType  {time: 'Wie spat is es?'}
const t1 = getUnion('ASK')
```

Unfortunately that's incorrect assumption as we're getting whole union instead of that one narrowed type

```
// ✅$ExpectType {"WUT?" | { hello: 'Guten Tag!'; time?: undefined; } | { time: 'Wie spat is es?'; hello?: undefined; }}
const t1 = getUnion('ASK')
```

Is this proper behaviour or rather Compiler limitation?

Anyways, how can this be solved?

So `const t1 = getUnion('ASK')` will return `{time: 'Wie spat is es?'}` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use a mapping interface instead of using a conditional type, makes the return type easier to follow. Also I generally use a separate implementation signature with the generics and an implementation signature that is not generic and returns a union. While this is not 100% type safe it is better than the type assertion version.

```
type Action = 'GREET' | 'ASK'
interface ProperReturn {
  'GREET': { hello: 'Guten Tag!' }
  'ASK': { time: 'Wie spat is es?' }
}
function getUnion<T extends Action>(action: T): ProperReturn[T]
function getUnion(action: Action): ProperReturn[keyof ProperReturn] {
  switch (action) {
    case 'GREET':
      return { hello: 'Guten Tag!' } as const
    case 'ASK':
      return { time: 'Wie spat is es?' } as const
    default:
      throw "WUT";
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAggxsAlgewHZQLxQOQHEBKAooQCrZQA+OMAygNLYBQiqwEATgGYCGc0ACu2SR2+CMACu7dAG9GUHAWJkAXFBlQAFhAA2O5GrwS26EtwDmAQnIBfedXrY1GpAFsIhgOqJoAZzDcwFCIvlAQvgD8tox2nBKoCCjo5uIAqqhJADwkYQAeJgAmofBIaAB8ABS8pahqJACUaoLCHGKS0gDaJAC6jHEJNVApwOlJVYloaiVJjVDNIm1SqB0A1hAgyJxzQgviS93q9r4A7ojAcJpQ4zX1hwoKcNy+0HhEpE7291Dse9LqWrp9IZcMYIKYLNYoDYoE8oHA0L5gJ84U8XrQGCpkQofu1ZFA3B4cN4-AEgiEwpFbDDQvDUIjkQUIDwJDpgJivgpgJohMcoAAiTypEh8gDc9jsNiAA)

Comment: yup, cleaner than my proposed solution. marking this one as solution. Cheers folks !

Answer (score 2):

So what I came up with is following:

This implementation mitigates previous issue, as it properly returns narrowed type from return union by used function argument, via conditional types mapper:

```
type ProperReturn<T> = T extends 'GREET' ? {hello:'Guten Tag!'} : T extends 'ASK' ? {time:'Wie spat is es?'} : 'WUT'
```

```
function getUnionStrict<T extends Action>(action: T): ProperReturn<T> {
  switch (action) {
  case 'GREET':
    // it needs to be explicitly casted, which is OK I guess?
    return {hello: 'Guten Tag!' } as ProperReturn<T>
  case 'ASK':
    //  Cast needed
    return {time:'Wie spat is es?'} as ProperReturn<T>
  default:
    //  Cast needed
    return 'WUT?' as ProperReturn<T>
  }
}
```

```
// ✅ exactly what we wanted 
// $ExpectType {hello:'Guten Tag!'}
const t11 = getUnionStrict('ASK')

// ✅
// $ExpectType {time:'Wie spat is es?'}
const t22 = getUnionStrict('GREET')
```

Comment: There's no way for `"WUT?"` to be returned, right?  I'd probably make a type like `interface ProperReturn {GREET: {hello: string}; ASK: {time: string}}` and have the return type be `ProperReturn[T]` and skip both the conditional type and the impossible `"WUT"?` return.  But essentially you're right that you need to define the return type conditions yourself and then do assertions (or a single-call-signature overload, which is often easier)

Answer (score 0):

For searchers like me: I came up with a mix of the two answers, that I think is both type-safe and cleaner:

```
type ProperReturn = {
  'GREET': { hello: 'Guten Tag!' }
  'ASK': { time: 'Wie spat is es?' }
}

// better than retyping 'GREET' | 'ASK'
type Action = keyof ProperReturn

function getUnion<T extends Action>(action: T): ProperReturn[T] {
  switch (action) {
  case 'GREET':
    return {hello: 'Guten Tag!' } as ProperReturn[T]
  case 'ASK':
    return {time:'Wie spat is es?'} as ProperReturn[T]
  default:
    throw "WUT?"
  }
}

// t1: { hello: 'Guten Tag!'; }
const t1 = getUnion('GREET')

// t2: { time: 'Wie spat is es?'; }
const t2 = getUnion('ASK')
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTge0nAShYBXOA7KBeKAbwCgooByAcRQFEaAVcgLiKgAsIAbThFqjYBFz0AhgHMAhOSgBfUhQCCAZQDSzVsACWAWwh8A6pugBnMCOBRNxqBGMB%20aXLnEA9C6gAjdILhRgbEVw4dHBNbDEKajpGKAAfRVVyYlBIKAUAYy0EXAIAawgQBAAzWERkNEwcYmIijGxMzWyoMXQAVWxG7AAeehsAD0FsABNrDKzsAD4AChEG7JZ6AEoWeCQIVHQsbABtegBdInljAHdNYHS2KBm57EXDsnSRY2gqWgZmeTJgytxCDm5eJEBEIoKJJI4oE9SmsNj9dnt5I9ngk1ExPlBvlsiFpdExyIYTGYLFYbPZyDJIdZVuVNjh4fIhhAiiIMJxgGiyGR-IhjlAAET6Vr0Ox8%20ROapuPwARhYhHYXB4fEowOE4ikAG5ZMR0tljBZgFL8M02h1slNXtFyIsJe5gAAmWV%20HR6CgEqCmcyWay2ByauQ67B6vx2o0tYDtTrm5RqRZAA)